# Is there a powershell command to add ipRules to CosmosDB in azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, firewall

I'm trying to add an ip to the network rules of CosmosDb (firewall) in azure, using powershell.

A lot of other resources seem to have a command available to do this (eg.  [keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/add-azkeyvaultnetworkrule?view=azps-5.8.0)  `Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName myvault -IpAddressRange "10.0.1.0/24"`), but I can't find any for CosmosDb. Does anyone know if it actually exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Update-AzCosmosDBAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/update-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-5.8.0)

```
$resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup"
$accountName = "my-cosmos-account"
$ipFilter = @("10.0.0.0/8", "11.0.1.0/24")
$allowAzureAccess = $true

if ($true -eq $allowAzureAccess) {
    $ipFilter += "0.0.0.0"
}

Update-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-Name $accountName -IpRangeFilter $ipFilter
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! would it then also be possible to add 1 ip to an exisiting range of ip's? Or would that be a matter of collecting all existing ip's, appending & then updating the account

Comment: Yes, do a Get-AzCosmosDBAccount and save the ipAddress to a string array, then += the new ipAddress and call Update.

Comment: @MarkBrown Can you help me with the script on how to append the IP's to the existing one and also if the respective IP is already availbale it should ignore or give a comment saying the IP is already available

Comment: @nikonD3400, comparing and deduping values in an array in PowerShell is a question better directed at the PowerShell tag, vs. this one.